# How to add printed data i.e. odr_id of terminal to database using model.py or any alternative option?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, selenium

I have created selenium project which automates mobile recharge. In my selenium file, I want to add printed data i.e. odr_id of terminal to database using model.py or any alternative option?

After completion of "recharge successful" I need to send a success receipt into my database. I used `print(order_id.text)` to get receipt in my terminal. now I don't know how to send that receipt to my database (I am using sqlite3)

```
odr_id = pay.find_element_by_id('deep-dtyp-order-details-section')
sleep(3)
print(odr_id.text)

#views.py
def odr(request):
    name = odr_id.GET(request)

    return [Amazon.order_detail, name]


pass
```

Comment: you should add detailed description of what are you trying to achieve, describe your code and what your problem is.

Comment: actually I'm new to Django, I have created selenium project in which It automates mobile recharge. After completion of "recharge successful" I needed to send successful receipt  into my database.
I used print(order_id.text) to get receipt in my terminal. now I don't know how to send that receipt to my database (i am using sqlite3)